# In gimp, how do I apply a transformation layer?

Tags: gimp, transform

Sorry for the totally newbie question, but: I've used the Resize tool on a layer of an image. I'm satisfied with the result, but what I have now is a transform layer about the original layer and I can't seem to "apply" it, and then be able to do other layer magic, like remove layer masks for the underlying layers etc. I can't find how to apply... what am I missing?

Using Gimp 2.8.16 on GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 0):

If what you have is a "Floating selection", you can make is a plain layer with `Layer>To new layer` (or Ctrl-shift-N).

You have a floating selection because there was a selection when you started the tool. If there is no selection the behavior is different, the initial layer is transformed and no floating selection is created. This behavior (common to all the transform tools) is AFAIK the one case where "no selection" and "full selection" have different results.